# Adding Placemarks on Google Earth API

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, kml, google-earth-plugin

Is it possible to allow a user to browse a Google Earth, and decide to add a placemark? I am using Google Earth API.

For example, if the user puts the mouse on a location, to automatically calculate the Long/Alt.

Thank you & regards
Bilal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a good [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/events.html) in the section "Draggable placemark".
In addition, there are many very good code samples around. I would recommend:

- [Creating Placemarks](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/placemark-point.html)
- [Draggable Placemark](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/placemark-dragdrop.html)
- [Placemark Click Event Handling](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/event-placemark.html)
- [Interactive Samples](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/interactive/index.html)